# How to compare list of array to another array using typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, arraylist, compare

i have a list of array and a single array. I want to compare this 2 array like this if productID  and attributesData match return something my list structure given below

List1:

```
    {
        "unitPrice": "800.0",
        "productTypeTitle": "TYPE",
       
        "productId": "470",
        
        "attributesData": [
            {
                "attributeName": "COLOR",
                "attributeData": "BLUE"
            },
            {
                "attributeName": "SIZE",
                "attributeData": "36"
            },
           {..}
        ],
        "count": 2,
        "shopid": "53",
        "sessionid": "1643195257593",
...
    },
    {
        },...
]
```

List2:

```
{
    "unitPrice": "800.0",
    "productTypeTitle": "TYPE",
    "productId": "470",
    "attributesData": [
        {
            "attributeName": "SIZE",
            "attributeData": "42"
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "COLOR",
            "attributeData": "Orange"
        },{...}
    ]
...
}
```

Here productId is same  but attributesData not same how can I find out that.I am able check if productId is same or not but unable to compare attributesData .How I can solve this problem of efficient way

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash isEqual, https://docs-lodash.com/v4/is-equal/

```
function isEqual(list1,list2):boolean{
return isEqual(list1,list2)
}
```

if not using lodash
-then you need to cycle through all the properties and compare

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {
    if (a === b) {
        return true;
    }
 
    if (a == null || typeof(a) != "object" ||
        b == null || typeof(b) != "object")
    {
        return false;
    }
 
    var propertiesInA = 0, propertiesInB = 0;
    for (var property in a) {
        propertiesInA += 1;
    }
    for (var property in b) {
        propertiesInB += 1;
        if (!(property in a) || !deepEqual(a[property], b[property])) {
            return false;        
        }
    }        
    return propertiesInA == propertiesInB;
}
```

this link  source
[enter link description here](https://tutovblog.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-javascript/)

because object is reference when process equaling

Comment: this will not work for me your function comparing whole list i need to compare based on productID and attributesData